# PowerShell Remoting not working with an Azure VM

Tags: azure, powershell

I'm trying to connect to a VM hosted in Azure and for some reason the remoting connection never established like you would typically see while on a corporate network.

Things I've checked:

- Enabled PS Remoting on the VM and validated the server shows it's enabled.
- Azure VM shows inbound connections are allowed on port 5985.

[image: Azure VM Connection Troubleshooter]

> **Note:** This issue was originally posted on Sitecore Slack by [Kamruz Jaman](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/users/135/jammykam) and I moved here to preserve the information.

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of trial and error I got it working.

Troubleshooting:

- Used `Test-NetConnection` on port 5985 using the public IP and full domain name to the machine. This failed until completely disabling the firewall on the VM.
- Ultimately the Windows Firewall had a WinRM rule on the public profile set to **Local Subnet only**. Changing to **Any IP** solved the issue. Defining the proper IP ranges would be better longer term.

[image: WinRM Inbound Rule]

[image: WinRM Advanced Properties]

[image: WinRM Scope]